# The LINQ expression could not be translated!? why?

Tags: c#, linq, expression, linq-expressions

I'm trying to retrieve a few records from a table given a certain condition... this is my code:

```
var areas = _context.Set<T>()
                .Where(p => (int)p.GetType().GetProperty(campoOrdem).GetValue(p) >= indexMin &&
                    (int)p.GetType().GetProperty(campoOrdem).GetValue(p) <= indexMax).ToList();
```

I am getting this error :

> 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<RH_Cargos>
> .Where(r => (int)r.GetType().GetProperty(__campoOrdem_0).GetValue(r) >=
> __indexMin_1 && (int)r.GetType().GetProperty(__campoOrdem_0).GetValue(r) <=
> __indexMax_2)' could not be translated.

All of my variables are getting the correct values.. campoOrdem is the string which contains the name of the field, indexMin and indexMax is my values of order in the database, in the example, indexMin is 1, and indexMax is 2...

what is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that chain of reflection calls can be translated? Why don't use values from `p` directly?

Comment: I can´t use values from p because they don´t exist... _context.Set<> doesn´t know wich table it will be used, it can be any table, that's why... So i pass the T to get table i want, and i pass a string wich is the name of the property i want to change in that table... :/

Comment: Not sure if it's clear to you, but using linq methods for sql requests implies that there is an "adapter". Those adapters have a limited logic to try to convert various expressions to sql. They are usually not able to translate anyhing you write to the proper SQL query for your database, even though as human programmer you would guess how to do it. Typically, I don't think taking into account reflection methods are usually part of the adapter capabilities.

Comment: To give a more direct example, the adapter asks itself, "ok, I see this `GetType()` method in the expression. How do I translate this to a SQL query?`".

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Why don't you use RH_Cargos as T directly then? What are you trying to do then with reflection? Consider the performance impact of reflection if this query would supposedly work. Reflection should be used with care. The piece of code you wrote won't be translated into a proper SQL query, because LINQ needs to know what you, as programmer, already 'implicitly' know. Furthermore, that piece of code isn't reusable, neither is really readable.

Comment: What i was trying to achieve is to reuse code, i have this code in everysingle controller, they are like 10 by now, wich means i wanted to make a generic one.. that's why i am trying to pass T instead of RH_Cargos right away... Since this is not possible to do, is there any other way to make a code to update a database field generic (so that i can just call the same piece of code in all controllers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection won't work for what you are trying to do, but if the property always has the same name, you could use generic constraints (if you can add that interface to all relevant entities):

```
 public interface IEntityWithCampoOrdem
 {
     public int CampoOrdem { get; } // property name should always be the same
 }
```

This assumes that entities like `RH_Cargos` can be defined like so:

```
 public class RH_Cargos : IEntityWithCampoOrdem
 {
      // other properties

      public int CampoOrdem { get; set; }
 }
```

Now you can create a generic method like so:

```
 public void GetAreas<T>() where T : IEntityWithCampoOrdem
 {
     var areas = _context.Set<T>()
            .Where(p => p.CampoOrdem >= indexMin &&
                p.CampoOrdem <= indexMax).ToList();
 }
```

Comment: It doesn´t have the same name but that can be arranged... Still i did not understand.. CampoOrdem shouldn´t be a name ? then why is it a int?

Comment: Your comment does not make sense to me. Maybe you should share the code of RH_Cargos. I edited to claryfy what I mean, but maybe the property is not called `CampoOrdem` (I just assumed that)

Comment: I was just being stupid, i got it now !! I am going to try this! thanks! :)